# Прикрепить файл к контактной форме (Magento)

Tags: cms, magento

Как сделать так, чтобы при прикреплении к форме файла файл отправлялся менеджеру на почту вместе с контактной информацией о заполнявшем её?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос уже староват, но так как ответа нет то напишу.

Если в общем то добавляем в шаблоне формы input[type=file] для выбора файла, переписываем контроллер в котором принимаем файл и атачим его к письму, вот тут в моем [гист](https://gist.github.com/evgv/cf073067a3874c25c56e7f03e9d3129a) есть пример как атачить файл к письму ZF/Magento